# Binding an array of formdata including file

Tags: go, postman, multipartform-data

I want to capture data into my struct from formdata.

```golang
type Ashish struct {
    Ashish []MerchantRuleBulkRequest `form:"ashish"`
}

type MerchantRuleBulkRequest struct {
    MerchantID     string         `form:"merchantId"`
    Product        string         `form:"product"`
    BlacklistField string         `form:"blacklistField"`
    FileToUpload   multipart.File `form:"file"`
}
```

The usual `c.Bind()` is not working. I have also tried using this `github.com/monoculum/formam/v3` implementation but not sure if it is able to parse multipart file.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What error, or other unexpected behavior, do you see? Include your code.

Comment: Normally, form do not support nested structures like json. You can see key-value input box in postman form data. Better way: 1. provide upload file api and return the file url; 2. replace `FileToUpload `to `FileUrl string` only save data with json.